# Pointer to a member-function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, member

I would like to do the following:
I have two classes, A and B, and want to bind a function from A to a function from B so that whenever something calls the function in B, the function from A is called.

So basically, this is the scenario:
(**important** A and B should be independent classes)

This would be class A:

```
class A {
private:
    // some needed variables for "doStuff"
public:
    void doStuff(int param1, float *param2);
}
```

This is class B

```
class B {
private:
    void callTheFunction();

public:
    void setTheFunction();   

}
```

And this is how I would like to work with these classes:

```
B *b = new B();
A *a = new A();

b->setTheFunction(a->doStuff); // obviously not working :(
```

I've read that this could be achieved with std::function, how would this work? Also, does this  have an impact in the performance whenever `callTheFunction()` is called? In my example, its a audio-callback function which should call the sample-generating function of another class.

Comment: What parameters would you pass to the function?

Comment: Examples of std::function here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: Would look something like this:

`void callback(float *output, int frames);`
But this could change, I'm not that far yet.

Comment: Use an `std::function<void(int, float *)>` member and populate it with a `bind` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution based on usage C++11 std::function and std::bind.

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using functionType = std::function <void (int, float *)>;

class A
{
public:
    void doStuff (int param1, float * param2)
    {
        std::cout << param1 << " " << (param2 ? * param2 : 0.0f) << std::endl;
    };
};

class B
{
public:
    void callTheFunction ()
    {
        function (i, f);
    };

    void setTheFunction (const functionType specificFunction)
    {
        function = specificFunction;
    };

    functionType function {};
    int     i {0};
    float * f {nullptr};
};

int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    using std::placeholders::_2;

    A a;
    B b;
    b.setTheFunction (std::bind (& A::doStuff, & a, _1, _2) );
    b.callTheFunction ();

    b.i = 42;
    b.f = new float {7.0f};
    b.callTheFunction ();

    delete b.f;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile:

> $ g++ func.cpp -std=c++11 -o func

Output:

> $ ./func
>
> 0 0
>
> 42 7

Comment: lovely! 
But I still have a question: What is _1 and _2 used for? And does this have an impact on the performance? (Only `b.callTheFunction()`);

Comment: `And does this have an impact on the performance?`, as far as I'm concerned `std::function` is template, so it's no runtime overhead from using it. `What is _1 and _2 used for?` it's placeholders 
which provide runtime function parameter substitution (try replacing `_1` on `333`).

Comment: Just so you know, the mechanic works nicely with my little audi-application. ;)

Comment: @ruhigbrauner, thanks, it's sounds good. One more note: you must guarantee lifetime of binded object during usage of function! If you don't consequences will be disastrous!

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought already yesterday. ;) But still it's more elegant to keep the two classes completely independent in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic skeleton:

```
struct B
{
    A * a_instance;
    void (A::*a_method)(int, float *);

    B() : a_instance(nullptr), a_method(nullptr) {}

    void callTheFunction(int a, float * b)
    {
        if (a_instance && a_method)
        {
            (a_instance->*a_method)(a, b);
        }
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
A a;

B b;
b.a_instance = &a;
b.a_method = &A::doStuff;

b.callTheFunction(10, nullptr);
```

Comment: Hi, 

this would obviously work but I want to keep A and B seperated. In my example `B` is an interface-class for audio-output and `A` is a class which generates audio-samples These two shouldn't be connected together since `B` should not care how the audio samples are generated.

Comment: @ruhigbrauner: That's the kind of information that would have been *really useful* in your question.

Comment: It's hard to guess what level I am but I could have done it when this wouldn't be a restriction.  :) Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

This i basic a solution

```
class A {
private:
    // some needed variables for "doStuff"
public:
    void doStuff(int param1, float *param2)
    {

    }
};

typedef void (A::*TMethodPtr)(int param1, float *param2);

class B {
private:

    TMethodPtr m_pMethod;
    A* m_Obj;

    void callTheFunction()
    {
      float f;
      (m_Obj->*m_pMethod)(10, &f);
    }


public:
    void setTheFunction(A* Obj, TMethodPtr pMethod)
    {
       m_pMethod = pMethod;
       m_Obj = Obj;
    }
};

   void main()
   {
      B *b = new B();
      A *a = new A();
      b->setTheFunction(a, A::doStuff); // now work :)
   }
```

Comment: Hi, 

sadly i forgott to mention that A and B shoudl be seperated. Sorry!
I will add this to the question for future readers. However, I like the Idea of `TMethodPtr`.