# Passing member function (or workaround)

Tags: c++

I want to do the following:

```
class A{
private:
  //some data
  B b;
  double f(double);
public:
  A(){
    b = new B(f); // does not work of course
  }
};

class B{
public:
  B(double (*func)(double));
};
```

Class B is supposed to solve a mathematical problem specified by the function func. Class A should now use B to solve this problem for func=f. The member function f accesses the private data members of A.
The problem is, of course that I cannot simply pass a pointer to member function. I know there are ways to do that, but B should still be able to take any function, not only members of A.
Until now, I just made f and the members of A static, but I think this is a rather bad design. Can you think of any workaround for this?

Comment: Use a `std::function`. If you need to shove an object for `this` into a member function, it's now easy to do so. If the member function doesn't use `this`, make it a free function or `static`.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230726/pointer-to-a-member-function/24231066#24231066) looks like similar.

Comment: Thank you, `std::function` looks fine, I will try that later. I'm not really into C++11, so maybe that's why I didn't find it.

Comment: @cthl, `boost::function` existed before C++11 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a fully working program for your sample.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class B
{
    public:
        B(std::function<double(double)> func)
        {
            std::cout<<func(1.0);
        }
};

class A
{
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<B> b;

        double f(double)
        {
            std::cout<<"A::f";
            return 2.0;
        }

    public:
        A() : b(new B(std::bind(&A::f, this, std::placeholders::_1)))
        {
        }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Please note you don't destroy `b` there and also keep in mind you are passing `this` to `B`, thing that might be dangerous (`B` might be alive after `A` is destroyed and if you use `this` inside `f`... boom!).

I would also suggest avoiding pointers and if this is not possible using `std::unique_ptr`

EDIT: And a version without `b` as pointer, `std::function` and `std::bind`

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

class B
{
    public:
        B(A* obj, double(A::*func)(double))
        {
            std::cout<<(obj->*func)(1.0);
        }
};

class A
{
    private:
        B b;
        double f(double)
        {
            std::cout<<"A::f";
            return 2.0;
        }

    public:
        A():b(this, &A::f)
        {
        }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Comment: There should be a `delete` for that `new B(...)` in the dtor (or you could use [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)  :) )

Comment: I know, I just pointed that in the answer:) I wanted to keep his original code. I will edit it because it might be confusing

Comment: Thanks. I know that I have to delete `b` in the destructor. I just did not write it here to keep things simple. I will try the std::function/std::bind combination now.

Comment: When I try out your example, everything works fine. But in my program the creation of `B` and thus the call to `std::bind` yields a segmentation violation...

Comment: Sorry, the segfault was my mistake. Everything works fine now, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

How about using polymorphism as an alternative to your current design?

For example:

```
class A
{
protected:
    virtual double f(double x) = 0;
};

class B1 : public A
{
public:
    double f(double x) {return x+1.0;}
};

class B2 : public A
{
public:
    double f(double x) {return x+2.0;}
};

...

A* arr[4];
arr[0] = new B1;
arr[1] = new B2;
arr[2] = new B1;
arr[3] = new B2;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    cout << arr[i]->f(0.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I think I cannot use this for my particular problem. I have to use tens and hundreds of different functions f and all of them depend on the input of the program, i.e. I do not know them in advance. Moreover, I'm working on a mathematical simulation, so performance is really an issue here. With your design I would have millions of calls to virtual functions.

Comment: @cthl Probably the virtual calls is nothing compared to the actual computation. Try it and make the optimisations later if they are really required. I would go for a clean and safe approach with virtual calls:)

Comment: @cthl: You're welcome. Please note that a virtual function is essentially a function pointer (i.e., in both cases, an additional memory-load operation is applied whenever the function is called). So there is no difference in terms of runtime performance, whether you use one mechanism or the other.

Comment: @Felics: Thanks. In any case, in terms of runtime performance, there is no difference between using a virtual function and using a function pointer (see my comment above).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard [`std::function<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) template as a polymorphic wrapper for your functions.

---

Your class `B` simply store an instance of `std::function<double (double)>` and call it through `foo` :

```
class B
{
  public:
    B(const std::function<double (double)>& func) : func(func) {}

    void foo(double d) 
    {
       std::cout << func(d);   
    }

  private:
    std::function<double (double)> func;
};
```

While your class `A` build its `B` member with one of its member function (`f`), thanks to [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) :

```
class A
{   
  public:
    double md;
    B b;

    double f(double d) const
    {
      return md * d;
    }

  public:
    A(double d) : md(d), b(std::bind(&A::f, this,  std::placeholders::_1)) { }
};
```

We can now simply use it :

```
int main() {
   A a(42);
   a.b.foo(2); // Output : 84
}
```

**[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3324a255549cf97c)**.

Answer (score 0):

Since function f() is not static it's type is "double ( A::* )(double)", not "double (*)(double)".

However for this particular case it is better re-design.

Does really A consist of data and instance of problem solver (class B), or A consist of data and delegates some operations to B?

Does really class B need some to know about methods from class A, or it expects data in some format?

```
class DataType {};
class ResultType {};
class A
{
    DataType data;
    DataType preprocess(Data d) {/*...*/}
    ResultType process() { return B::compute(data); }
    bool isSolvable() { return B::solve(preprocess(data)); }
};
class B
{
public:
    ResultType compute(DataType);
    bool solve(DataType);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
class A
{
    B* b;
    static double f(double d); //static change function type form `double(A::*)(double)` to `double(*)(double)`
public:
    A()
    {
        b = new B(f);
    }
}
```

only drawback that `f` cant take any data form `A` or `B`.